# When the app is in the background, does the APNS token change or become invalid?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

We have a problem we can't solve. While the application is waiting in the background, we think the APNS token has changed.

That's why we're wondering.

When the APNS token is changed or invalid. For example, in an application that waits 3 days in the background, can the APNS token be invalid?

If the token application can become invalid while in the background, it means that you should send the server a new token when this app comes to the foreground

If you can answer our questions, you will help us a lot. :)

Comment: This document answers all of those questions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APNS token will rarely change and it certainly won't change while the app is simply suspended or not running. Deleting and then re-installing the app will change if.

Regardless, each time your app launches you should call `registerForRemoteNotifications` and each time your `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` delegate method is called, update your back end.

Comment: yes I do that. thank you for your response. my only concern is that it's more accurate to do this after applicationDidBecomeActive

Comment: No, the delegate method will be called in any instance where the token changes, not just in response to calling `registerForRemoteNotifications`